# choropleth map does not render in Dashboard Studio but it does in Classic Dashboards

Tags: splunk, choropleth, splunk-dashboard

I need to plot a world map and color countries based on the count and this to a dashboard. This is my query

```
...<ommitted> AS iso2
| search iso2=*
| stats count by iso2
| lookup geo_attr_countries iso2 OUTPUT country
| fields+ count, country
| geom geo_countries featureIdField="country"
```

This works fine on the search page. When Visualization=Choropleth Map is chosen it plots correctly. I add it on a Classic Dashboard type dashboard and it works fine. But when I add the same query to a Dashboard Studio type dashboard, it doesn't work. I get an error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'warn')
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Know your data columns
> When you create a search to generate a choropleth map, the search will have a column of fields, usually states, countries, or regions. This column is usually equivalent to the setting primary[0], the first column of results. There should be at least one more column that relates a numeric value to each field in the first column (color for NULL values can also be configured). This is often, but not always, the second column in the search results, equivalent to the setting primary[1]. If the number values you want to use are in a different column, use the equivalent setting primary[n-1] where n equals the number of the column.

Documentation - https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.1.0/DashStudio/mapsChor

As per this, I modified my query to the one below and it worked

```
| fields+ country, count
```